# java wont let me increment these arrays by 2. keep getting an error that their not statments

Tags: java, arrays, increment

```
public static boolean isUPC(int [] UPC) 
{
    int checkDigit;
    int sum2;
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i < UPC.length;i+2)
    sum += UPC[i];

    sum = sum * 3;
    int sum1 = 0;
    for(int j = 1;j < UPC.length;j+2)
    sum1 += UPC[i];

    sum2 = sum + sum1;

    checkDigit = 10 - (sum2 % 10);

    if(checkDigit == UPC[11])
    return true;
    else
    return false;                                                                           
}
```

the for loops with the `i+2` and `j+2` wont work don't have a clue why not

Answer (score 5):

It should be i += 2 in the the for loop

Answer (score 2):

The format for a for loop increment is:

```
for(int i = 0;i < UPC.length;i += 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `for(int i = 0;i < UPC.length;i+2)`

Try:

`for(int i = 0;i < UPC.length;i=i+2)`

Answer (score 0):

The for right syntax should be:

for(int j = 1;j < UPC.length;i += 2)

Answer (score 0):

`for` loop works this way -

1st statement indicates what is executed before the inner loop execution.
2nd statement indicates the condition which is checked for true every iteration of loop.
3rd statement indicates what is executed at the end of every inner loop.

So in your case, you need to write statement that will be executed at the end of your inner loop. That statement has the same semantics as every other java statement, thus it is i+=2, because you to increment i by 2, not just throw in a value of i+2 somewhere.